# How to push rtmp using deepar result

Tags: android, rtmp, deepar

I want to stream deepar videos using rtmp.

And followed agora's example [here](https://github.com/DeepARSDK/videocall-android-java/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ai/deepar/videocall/DeepARRenderer.java).

But I don't want to use agora's server.

I have an SRS server on my local server.

I tried this to get deepar's result from opengl. It worked.

```
GLES20.glReadPixels(x, 0, w, y + h, GLES20.GL_RGBA,
            GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
```

use [rtmp client](https://github.com/ant-media/LibRtmp-Client-for-Android) to push data from opengl.

```
public native int writeVideo(byte[] data, int offset, int length, int timestamp);
```

I got return -1, it means send video fail.

examples, other rtmp client lib, any hint, will appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am done with [rtmp-rtsp-stream-client-java](https://github.com/pedroSG94/rtmp-rtsp-stream-client-java).

Comment: Links can be broken over time. If you can drop more information about the page it would be more helpful for the future.